# Easy to read Golang assembly output?

Tags: go, assembly, x86

I'm interested in examining the x86 assembly output of the standard Go compiler to see if my code is really being converted into reasonably efficient assembly code; hopefully, by profiling and examining the assembly output, I could get a clue as to where/how I should rewrite my Go code for maximum performance. But when I examine the code using the -S flag, Go spits out a mess! I'd like two things:

1. Is there a way to make the Go compiler dump the assembly output into a file, not just print it out on Terminal?
2. Also, is there a way to make the Go compiler separate out the assembly code into separate functions, with labels? I know some functions may be inlined and hence not appear in the assembly code. What I'm seeing know is just a homogenous blob of assembly which is almost impossible to understand.

Comment: 1) What about using `>` or whatever your command shell supports for redirecting the output of a command to a file?

Comment: Also, your approach to profiling by looking at the assembly code may not be the most productive one. Have you looked at the profiling tools available for Go code? (e.g. http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs)

Comment: I agree with you, assembly output needs some improvement. The problem is that the Go compiler does not generate actual assembly. It generates something that looks a lot like assembly but contains a lot of pseudo-instructions that will be expanded by the linker. Only after linking is done, actual assembly is produced (and immediately assembled).

Comment: Also, have a look at [how the Plan 9 assembler works](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/asm.html). The reference implementation of Go uses this assembler.

Comment: PS: I'm looking for something similar to the GCC command: -fverbose-asm

Answer (score 47):

1. You can redirect the output to a file like this:

   ```
    go tool compile -S file.go > file.s
   ```
2. You can disable the optimization with -N:

   ```
    go tool compile -S -N file.go
   ```

Alternatively, you can use gccgo:

```
gccgo -S -O0 -masm=intel test.go
```

which will generate test.s. You can play with the -O0/1/2/3 to see the different optimizations.

Comment: `go build -gcflags -S test.go > test.s` should work, too (according to https://golang.org/doc/asm)

Comment: `go tool comile -S file.go > file.S` since `go1.5`

Comment: @IvanBlack Your comment deserves a top-level response.

Comment: tried to add the original to add what @IvanBlack said (only since go.15 for "go tool compile"), but the edit queue is full.   Perhaps author may want to.  Not a big deal though, these versions get old so quick...

Answer (score 24):

I don't recommend using the output of `-S` as the Go linker can change what gets written to the object code quite a lot. It does give you some idea as to what is going on.

The go assembler output is rather non-standard too.

When I want to do this I always use [objdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) which will give you a nice standard assembler output.

Eg for x86 / amd64

```
objdump -d executable > disassembly
```

And for ARM (to get the register names to be the same as Go uses)

```
objdump -M reg-names-raw -d executable > disassembly
```

Comment: Example assembly syntax to be expected with these is: `mov    %r11b,0x84(%rsp,%r10,1)`   Just sayin',

Answer (score 15):

Run `go tool objdump` on the resulting executable file.

To restrict the output to interesting functions, use its `-s` option.

Answer (score 9):

To dump the output to file:

```
go tool objdump EXECUTABLE_FILE > ASSEMBLY_FILE
```

If you want to include the source Go code (assuming you have a working golang setup, and you built the executable yourself):

```
go tool objdump -S EXECUTABLE_FILE
```

To make the output even easier to look at I use a [small hacky wrapper](https://gist.github.com/CAFxX/332b425634f12ccbb7a1eef074da19bf) that produces the following (in a nutshell, it colorizes instructions that alter the control flow -blue for jumps, green for call/return, red for traps, violet for padding- and adds new lines after unconditional control flow jumps):

[image: example output of go-objdump wrapper]

If you use the wrapper above you will likely want to use the `-R` switch when piping to `less` (or by adding it to the environment, e.g. in `.bashrc`: `export LESS="$LESS -R"`):

```
go-objdump EXECUTABLE_FILE | less -R
```

Alternatively, there is [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) that has probably the most readable output and allows you to switch between compilers (gc, gccgo) and versions very easily.

Answer (score 8):

A recent alternative would be [**`loov/lensm`**](https://github.com/loov/lensm), which can view assembly and source.
(From [**Egon Elbre**](https://twitter.com/egonelbre/status/1547938616805978114))

> To run the program, provide a regular expression filter for the symbol you want to inspect.
> `-watch` allows to automatically reload the executable and information when it changes.
>
> ```
> lensm -watch -filter Fibonacci lensm
> ```
>
> Note: The program requires a binary that is built on your computer, otherwise the source code for the functions cannot be loaded.
>
> Result:
>
> [image: https://github.com/loov/lensm/blob/main/screenshot.png?raw=true]

---

That could be a nice addition to [**godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/)

[image: godbolt.org]

Answer (score 3):

I had problems with the other answers as the assembly produced provided much more information than I wanted and still not enough details. Let me explain: it provided the assembly for all libraries imported by go internally and did not provide the lines of where my code was (my code was all at the bottom of the file)

Here is what I found from the official docs:

`$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go tool compile -S x.go        # or: go build -gcflags -S x.go`

File:

```
package main

func main() {
    println(3)
}
```

Produces:

```
--- prog list "main" ---
0000 (x.go:3) TEXT    main+0(SB),$8-0
0001 (x.go:3) FUNCDATA $0,gcargs·0+0(SB)
0002 (x.go:3) FUNCDATA $1,gclocals·0+0(SB)
0003 (x.go:4) MOVQ    $3,(SP)
0004 (x.go:4) PCDATA  $0,$8
0005 (x.go:4) CALL    ,runtime.printint+0(SB)
0006 (x.go:4) PCDATA  $0,$-1
0007 (x.go:4) PCDATA  $0,$0
0008 (x.go:4) CALL    ,runtime.printnl+0(SB)
0009 (x.go:4) PCDATA  $0,$-1
0010 (x.go:5) RET     ,
```

So what I did was basically:

`go tool compile -S hello.go > hello.s`

and it got the result I wanted!

Comment: You might find the Godbolt compiler explorer useful for color highlighting to map source lines to asm.  https://godbolt.org/g/yQ4gbQ has output for a simple function with both gc1.10.1 and gccgo 7.2.

Comment: That is a really nice tool

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way i found around for Mac users with XCode dev tools is with `otool`

```
$ otool -tV <executable>
```

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/206552)