# How to inspect Go package files (.a files)?

Tags: go

How to inspect the content of Go package/object files (`.a`, `.o`)

The only thing I found is showing the full disassembly with `go tool objdump`.

But how to show the file structure, like imported and exported symbols, code, data and other sections, other metadata etc.?

Comment: See also "[Easy to read Golang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73001689/6309)", which is not targeted to a `.a` file, but can help nonetheless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compiled Go packages are stored in [Unix ar archive files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)), so you can extract the files within them using `ar` or `go tool pack x pkg.a`.

Package files contain compiled code (`_go_.o`), used by the linker to build binaries, and export data (`__.PKGDEF`), used by the compiler when building dependent packages. If the package contained assembly files or cgo code, there may be additional `.o` files, too.

You can use [`golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata) to read export data into a format that can be understood by [`go/types`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types).

It sounds like you've already found `go tool objdump` for disassembly. You might also find [`go tool nm`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/nm) useful for listing symbols.