# Are these 2 string allocations equivalent?

Tags: string, go, dynamic-memory-allocation

I saw this guy, and he wrote this code:

```golang
func foo1() *string {
    var pointa *string
    pointa = new(string)
    *pointa = "stuff"
    return pointa
}
```

Very nice, very nice, however, can't help but notice that one could also write:

```golang
func foo2() *string {
    var pointa *string
    var str = "stuff"
    pointa = &str
    return pointa
}
```

The first code says:

- dynamically allocate a string container with empty underlying storage
- override the underlying storage with contents of this literal
- I assume, because of COW, underlying storage just points to the literal's data in the data segment of ELF

The second code says:

- allocate locally an instance of a string
- but because it will later escape the scope via reference `&`, it will be allocated dynamically
- and still, because of COW, no copy will take place

Am I right about these assumptions?
Are these 2 dynamic string allocations equivalent?
Is `new(string); *pointer = "payload"` exactly what is happening in the second code, but under the hood, implicitly?

Are these pieces of code gonna produce the same code that allocated and initializes the string?

Comment: Escape analysis will decide that `"stuff"` needs to exist on the heap, because it needs to still exist after stack deallocation due to a pointer to it being returned. I'd expect the compiler to skip any stack allocation in both cases, unless inlining reveals the pointer does not escape further in any calling function. However, it's better to not make any assumptions about that.

Comment: [1/2] I know I will sound boring and dismissive but your question has little to no sense: the programming language Go is defined by its [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec), and the spec says nothing at all about allocations (let alone COW and specific formats of executable image files). I mean, you will not find there even such words as "stack" and "heap". This means, `new()` is defined to _create_ a new object of the specified type, initialize it with the zero value for that type and return an address of that object. It says nothing where and how that object will be allocated.

Comment: [2/2] You might think I sound like a language purist, but the most popular implementation of Go once gained support for `GOARCH=wasm`, and might gain support for more weird architectures in the future.

Comment: «I assume, because of COW, underlying storage just points to the literal's data in the data segment of ELF»–please note that this might indicate you're not yet familiar with strings in Go as otherwise you'd know strings are immutable (hence there's no need for COW), and a string is actually a small `struct` value consisting of a pointer and an integer. Reading <https://go.dev/blog/strings> is advised. All in all, it's okay if you're just fiddling. If the code being discussed is to show up in a real program, I urge you to step back and ponder that Go is probably not the language you need.

Comment: The only possible answer is "it depends" - it depends on the combination of compiler, compiler version, target OS, and target arch. More importantly, it doesn't matter: this appears to be a question written from very deep down the rabbit hole of premature optimization.

Comment: @Zyl thanks for the comment! Yeah, I understand that, but this doesn't really address my question...

Comment: @kostix thanks for commenting - I actually like your comment, thanks for clearing it out - that `new` semantically just creates the object and that's all I should be concerned about! And I really do understand it. However, my interest lies in the idea of how the actual initialization takes place in low level memory management terms. As in "are these pieces of code gonna produce the same code that allocates and initializes the string?"

Comment: @kostix I'm sorry, I read your comment about how strings work, and whoa, sorry, did you read my question? When a string is instantiated with a literal, does the payload get copied to the stack (or heap) from the `.rodata` section of ELF? Or is there a COW mechanism where it won't be copied and instead, the string will point to read-only segment where the string literal is stored in executable? I feel like there is a huge misunderstanding.

Comment: @kostix "you're not yet familiar with strings in Go", "ponder if go is not the language you need" - thank you for your kind words.

Comment: @Adrian thanks for the comment - nah, I'm not asking out of premature optimization, I'm asking out of "I wonder just how it works under the hood"

Comment: @IsaaсWeisberg, my comment was not intended to be an insult or something like this; if it sounded like that–I apologize! As to picking the language: yes, sometimes you have to tinker with Go in an attempt to squeeze a little bit in really hot places, but the particular subject you're touching in your question look like too low-level for Go, so maybe you need C++ or C, where you can have _precise_ control even for really low-end stuff.

Comment: @kostix Thank you. Yeaah... as I said, I really do get your point, it's important, what does the language imply semantically, but I was just interested in how it *really* works under the hood...

Comment: As to that "COW"-related issue. Two points: 1) While the compiler of the most popular implementation of Go is not as hardcore in its optimizations as many industrial C (and C++) comilers, you might be surprized by some tricks it has up its sleeve. For instance, when it comes to comparisons of a string to a small simple string literal–like `if s == "foobar"`–it's not uncommon to see direct comparisons (`CMPQ`) with raw sequences of bytes extracted from the literal (4s on i386 and 8s on amd64). I mean, a string literal in such case _is not even stored_ in `.rodata` or something like this!…

Comment: …Instead, it "gets embedded" right into the machine code instructions. 2) Note that COW means Copy On Write; strings in Go are immutable, so writes to them (to their data bytes) never occur. I mean, you'd better get rid of that term when discussing strings in Go: it sounds cool but IMO is not really applicable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255731/discussion-between-isaa-weisberg-and-kostix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go specification makes no guarantees, and whatever answer you discover today is subject to change without warning, but you can see for yourself using the version of `gc` available a godbolt.org that all three versions of your function produce **identical** output, differing only in the names and values of the string (stuff1/stuff2/stuff3):

https://godbolt.org/z/evP1M3fs5

```
func foo1() *string {
    var pointa *string
    pointa = new(string)
    *pointa = "stuff1"
    return pointa
}

func foo2() *string {
    var pointa *string
    var str = "stuff2"
    pointa = &str
    return pointa
}

func foo3() *string {
    x := "stuff3"
    return &x;
}
```

Output:

```
main_foo1_pc0:
        TEXT    main.foo1(SB), ABIInternal, $24-0
        CMPQ    SP, 16(R14)
        PCDATA  $0, $-2
        JLS     main_foo1_pc50
        PCDATA  $0, $-1
        PUSHQ   BP
        MOVQ    SP, BP
        SUBQ    $16, SP
        FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·g2BeySu+wFnoycgXfElmcg==(SB)
        FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·g2BeySu+wFnoycgXfElmcg==(SB)
        LEAQ    type:string(SB), AX
        PCDATA  $1, $0
        CALL    runtime.newobject(SB)
        MOVQ    $6, 8(AX)
        LEAQ    go:string."stuff1"(SB), CX
        MOVQ    CX, (AX)
        ADDQ    $16, SP
        POPQ    BP
        RET
main_foo1_pc50:
        NOP
        PCDATA  $1, $-1
        PCDATA  $0, $-2
        CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
        PCDATA  $0, $-1
        JMP     main_foo1_pc0
main_foo2_pc0:
        TEXT    main.foo2(SB), ABIInternal, $24-0
        CMPQ    SP, 16(R14)
        PCDATA  $0, $-2
        JLS     main_foo2_pc50
        PCDATA  $0, $-1
        PUSHQ   BP
        MOVQ    SP, BP
        SUBQ    $16, SP
        FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·g2BeySu+wFnoycgXfElmcg==(SB)
        FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·g2BeySu+wFnoycgXfElmcg==(SB)
        LEAQ    type:string(SB), AX
        PCDATA  $1, $0
        CALL    runtime.newobject(SB)
        MOVQ    $6, 8(AX)
        LEAQ    go:string."stuff2"(SB), CX
        MOVQ    CX, (AX)
        ADDQ    $16, SP
        POPQ    BP
        RET
main_foo2_pc50:
        NOP
        PCDATA  $1, $-1
        PCDATA  $0, $-2
        CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
        PCDATA  $0, $-1
        JMP     main_foo2_pc0
main_foo3_pc0:
        TEXT    main.foo3(SB), ABIInternal, $24-0
        CMPQ    SP, 16(R14)
        PCDATA  $0, $-2
        JLS     main_foo3_pc50
        PCDATA  $0, $-1
        PUSHQ   BP
        MOVQ    SP, BP
        SUBQ    $16, SP
        FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·g2BeySu+wFnoycgXfElmcg==(SB)
        FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·g2BeySu+wFnoycgXfElmcg==(SB)
        LEAQ    type:string(SB), AX
        PCDATA  $1, $0
        CALL    runtime.newobject(SB)
        MOVQ    $6, 8(AX)
        LEAQ    go:string."stuff3"(SB), CX
        MOVQ    CX, (AX)
        ADDQ    $16, SP
        POPQ    BP
        RET
main_foo3_pc50:
        NOP
        PCDATA  $1, $-1
        PCDATA  $0, $-2
        CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
        PCDATA  $0, $-1
        JMP     main_foo3_pc0
```

Comment: Exactly what I asked for!

Answer (score 6):

They are identical but verbose. The first one allocates a string pointer (which contains a pointer to the actual string contents and its length), then initializes that pointer to point to a string. The second one creates a local pointer, but since that pointer escapes the function, the compiler allocates that on heap. This can be simplified by:

```
func foo2() *string {
    var str = "stuff"
    return &str
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... hmmm... I wonder if they are REALLY identical...

Comment: @IsaaсWeisberg then compare the compiler output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789951/easy-to-read-golang-assembly-output

Comment: @Adrian I really should...

Comment: They are semantically equivalent. They are not necessarily identical.

Comment: @IsaaсWeisberg What people are trying to tell you here is that, if you actually care about whether they are "identical", Go is not the right language for this kind of question. Go makes no guarantee here. They could be identical in one compiler and not in another. They could be identical today and different tomorrow. You're wondering about things that make *no sense* to wonder about in Go, because there cannot exist a useful answer. If, for some reason, you insist on caring here, use https://godbolt.org to compare both cases.

Comment: Here: All three versions produce **exactly identical** instructions: https://godbolt.org/z/evP1M3fs5

Comment: @user229044 yessss that's exactly what I needed! Would you like to post this link as the answer and I will accept it?

Comment: @IsaaсWeisberg Sure, done